# SQL Server select distinct hell

Tags: sql-server, select, distinct

I'm stuck on a problem with sql. I have a table with many duplicate entries with column names like:-

```
eventnumber housenumber value1 value2
```

None of these column names are the primary key as there are many duplicates. What I would like to do is select into another table by distinct housenumber but I seem to get the whole table copied across, I'm using:-

```
Select * into temp_table from schedule_temp where housenumber in (select distinct housenumerb from schedule_temp)
```

Now I broke it down a bit and if I do:-

```
Select distinct housenumber into temp from schedule_temp group by housenumber
```

I get a table with the unique housenumbers... but then how could I use this unique table to drive another select that picks housenumbers from temp and only gets one instance of the housenumber from schedule_temp? Hope that makes sense.

Beers are on me if you can save my sanity.

Comment: Are *eventnumber*, *value1*, *value2* the same for a given *housenumber*? If not, how do you want to decide which to put into your table of unique *housenumbers*

Comment: your post also leads me to insanity. Can you rephrase to be more clear - particularly can you post a real schema sample and the final data that you want (not so much the half-steps)?

Comment: Ah sorry, the results should be showed by unique housenumber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'd get the data into a table with an auto increment id

So create a table with id,eventnumber,housenumber,value1, value2 where id is an auto number.

Then

```
Insert Into NewTemp(eventnumber,housenumber,value1, value2)
Select eventnumber,housenumber,value1, value2 From schedule_temp
```

Then this query should guve you 1 row per house #

```
Select nt.* From NewTemp nt
Join (select max(id) as id, housenumber from NewTemp Group By housenumber) t on t.id=nt.id
```

Comment: Many thanks brendan that gives me my data sorted by distinct housenumber which is what I'm after, but how do I put the result into a new table?

Comment: Select * Into SomeNewTable From Table1

Comment: Thanks, I should've known that... it's been a long day :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want DISTINCT records (as in, each record has at least one column different than all other records).  You want a winner from each group (or partition) of records.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    EventNumber, HouseNumber, Value1, Value2,
    ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER(PARTITION BY HouseNumber ORDER BY HouseNumber) as rowNum
  FROM ServiceAddr
) sub
WHERE sub.rowNum = 1
```