# SQL Server select distinct latest values

Tags: sql-server-2005, select, join, distinct

I have a table that has a ton of rows (>10K). Most of the rows have duplicate **role** values associated with the **username**.

What I am trying to do is select rows by distinct AND latest **role** added by **request_id**. 
I almost have it, but the part that is kicking my tail is there are `null` values in some of the **request_id** fields because those requests were made before that column was added. I **STILL** need to include them in the `select statement` in case a user has not entered another request since the update.

Here a example of my table structure:

```
 id | uname  | role    | request_id
 0  | jsmith  | User   | null
 1  | jsmith  | Admin   | null
 2  | jsmith  | Dude    | null
 3  | jsmith  | Admin   | 56
 4  | jsmith  | Dude    | 56
 5  | jsmith  | Admin   | 57
 6  | jsmith  | Dude    | 57
```

***This would be the desired result:***

```
0  | jsmith  | User    | null
5  | jsmith  | Admin   | 57
6  | jsmith  | Dude    | 57
```

Here are the statements I've tried so far:

## Join

```
select distinct a.uname, a.role, a.request_id from (
    select * from  das_table 
    ) 
b join das_table a on b.role = a.role and b.request_id = a.request_id
where a.uname = 'jsmith'
```

**Result:** This eliminates the rows with **request_id** = `NULL`

## MAX()

This didn't work for me I guess because `MAX()` doesn't count `null` values?

```
select distinct uname, role, max(request_id) as request_id from das_table where uname='jsmith'
group by uname, role, request_id
```

## Similar questions I've looked at:

One caveat in my question that I think makes it different from the others I've researched is the `request_id` having the possibility of being null.

[Select distinct values from 1 column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918556/sql-select-distinct-values-from-1-column) | 
[SQL Server : select distinct by one column and by another column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461902/sql-server-select-distinct-by-one-column-and-by-another-column-value) | 
[SQL Server select distinct hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247401/sql-server-select-distinct-hell)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `max` query didn't work because you included `request_id` in the grouping - try:

```
select distinct uname, role, max(request_id) as request_id 
from das_table where uname='jsmith'
group by uname, role
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70f70/1).

Comment: I am not sure the `distinct` clause is needed here as you are using `group by`.

Comment: The query is working perfectly but my concern is that how could I select other fields of that latest entry?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like ISNULL would solve your problem, I use 1 here for simplicity but you could use -1 if that makes more sense for your usage.

```
MAX(ISNULL(request_id, 1))
```