# PHP/MYSQL Distinct operator with multiple fields and field selection

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL table that looks like:

`+----+--------------+------------+----------------+---------------------+
| id | id_solicitud | id_estatus | id_responsable |     fecha_hora      |
+----+--------------+------------+----------------+---------------------+
|  1 |            1 |          1 |              3 | 2017-11-20 11:12:05 |
|  3 |            1 |          2 |              3 | 2017-11-20 13:30:50 |
|  4 |            2 |          1 |              5 | 2017-11-20 13:42:35 |
|  5 |            2 |          2 |              5 | 2017-11-20 13:52:25 |
|  6 |            1 |          4 |              2 | 2017-11-21 12:20:17 |
|  8 |            2 |          3 |              2 | 2017-11-21 13:39:57 |
|  9 |            2 |          2 |              5 | 2017-11-21 13:40:55 |
| 10 |            2 |          4 |              2 | 2017-11-21 13:45:24 |
+----+--------------+------------+----------------+---------------------+`

Then, I proceed to filter by the *id_solicitud* field with the following Mysql QUERY:

*SELECT id_estatus, id_responsable, fecha_hora FROM estatus_historico WHERE id_solicitud =2 ORDER BY fecha_hora*

The result:

`+------------+----------------+---------------------+
| id_estatus | id_responsable |     fecha_hora      |
+------------+----------------+---------------------+
|          1 |              5 | 2017-11-20 13:42:35 |
|          2 |              5 | 2017-11-20 13:52:25 |
|          3 |              2 | 2017-11-21 13:39:57 |
|          2 |              5 | 2017-11-21 13:40:55 |
|          4 |              2 | 2017-11-21 13:45:24 |
+------------+----------------+---------------------+`

I want to apply the distinct operator over *id_estatus* column but selecting the older row when duplicate rows are found, i.e. my desired result is:

`+------------+----------------+---------------------+
| id_estatus | id_responsable |     fecha_hora      |
+------------+----------------+---------------------+
|          1 |              5 | 2017-11-20 13:42:35 |
|          3 |              2 | 2017-11-21 13:39:57 |
|          2 |              5 | 2017-11-21 13:40:55 |
|          4 |              2 | 2017-11-21 13:45:24 |
+------------+----------------+---------------------+`

I tried:

*SELECT id_estatus, id_responsable, fecha_hora FROM estatus_historico WHERE id_solicitud =2 GROUP BY id_estatus ORDER BY fecha_hora*

But the result is wrong:

`+------------+----------------+---------------------+
| id_estatus | id_responsable |     fecha_hora      |
+------------+----------------+---------------------+
|          1 |              5 | 2017-11-20 13:42:35 |
|          2 |              5 | 2017-11-20 13:52:25 |
|          3 |              2 | 2017-11-21 13:39:57 |
|          4 |              2 | 2017-11-21 13:45:24 |
+------------+----------------+---------------------+`

Any help would be much appreciated

UPDATE: Files to create table and insert data => [estatus_historico.sql](http://antonioch.com/dummy/estatus_historico.sql)

Comment: You could apply `max` function to `id` field as stated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16966646/2131856

Comment: NOT WORKING: Thanks for your answer but *max(id_estatus)* in GROUP BY clause results on an error **#1111 - Invalid use of group function** and *max(id_estatus)* in the SELECT clause is the same wrong result

Comment: You should make sql create and insert statement for your table so people can help you easier

Comment: I have update the post with a link to the SQL file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

`SELECT id_estatus, id_responsable, MAX(fecha_hora) FROM estatus_historico WHERE id_solicitud =2 GROUP BY id_estatus ORDER BY fecha_hora`

[image]

Comment: This SQL sentence is the base for the correct answer, the only detail is that second and third rows are interchanged

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Rahul Shrivastava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7900369/rahul-shrivastava), I finally found the correct answer:

`SELECT * FROM (
SELECT id_estatus, id_responsable, MAX( fecha_hora ) AS fecha
FROM estatus_historico
WHERE id_solicitud =2
GROUP BY id_estatus
ORDER BY fecha_hora
) AS MY_TABLE ORDER BY fecha`